# Twig template engine shows odd information

Tags: php, twig

I am first day user of Twig, and I have some strange behaviour of engine.
I push some information to my view:

```
class MainController extends Controller {


public function actionIndex()
{

    $template = self::$twig->loadTemplate('index.php');
    $title = 'CRUD интерфейс';
    $projects = MainList::showAll();
    $workers = CompanyWorker::showAll();
    $roles = Role::showAll();
    $namesOfProjects = Project::showAll();
    echo $template->render(array(
        'title' => $title,
        'projects' => $projects,
        'workers' => $workers,
        'roles' => $roles,
        'namesOfProjects' => $namesOfProjects
    ));
}
```

}

In the end I have a good result but in the end of HTML file twig shows me my controller object. Why it's happened?

[image]

It's my Twig initialisation:
    abstract class Controller {

```
public $loader;
static $twig;


function __construct()

{
    $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views');
    //$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => 'cache'));
    self::$twig = new Twig_Environment($this->loader);
}
```

Comment: Are u sure u don't have a `var_dump`  somewhere else?

Comment: @DarkBee Ur right man! I am so blind...

Answer (score 0):

I'm were blind 8[. I really missed 'print_r' func.